# Integral solutions of a linear equation with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, combinations

For linear equation like: 
    $$x_1+ x_2+ x_3+ \dots x_r = n$$
All non negative integral solutions are: $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$

**CASE I:** If constraint is given like $x_1\geq a, x_2\geq b,\dots$
We can approach it like:
    $$(x_1'+ a)+ (x_2'+ b)+ \dots = n$$

**CASE II:** But if constraint is given like $a< x_1< a', b< x_2< b',\dots$ 
For this case, is there any general approach like CASE I ?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is $x_i'$?

Comment: x'i is just a simple variable replacing xi but is having lower limit of 0 or 1.